# Создание нескольких графиков в цикле matplotlib. subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Добрый вечер подскажите почему не работает. Необходимо что бы в первой строчке были гистограммы а в нижних строчках были барплоты.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

url='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K-tf97Hjklw_eHFxeup36bBpElSC1hrb/view?usp=sharing'
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + url.split('/')[-2]
data = pd.read_csv(url)
num_cols = [
    'ClientPeriod',
    'MonthlySpending',
    'TotalSpent'
]
#Убираю пустые строки в TotalSpent
data.TotalSpent = data.TotalSpent.apply(lambda x: float(x) if x.split() else 0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(18,18))


ax = ax.ravel()

for i, col in enumerate(num_cols):

    ax[i].set_title('Hist_table ' + col)
    ax[i].boxplot(data[col][:100])

    ax[i].set_title('Hist_table ' + col)
    ax[i].hist(data[col][:100])

  
   

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного перемудрили с индексированием axes - индексация идет по порядку от нулевой ax до ax ч номером (2*3 - 1).

В вашем случае быстрым решением можно считать такое:

```
for i in range(len(num_cols)):
    print(num_cols[i])
    ax[i].set_title('Hist_table ' + num_cols[i])
    ax[i].boxplot(data[num_cols[i]][:100])

    ax[i+len(num_cols)].set_title('Hist_table ' + col)
    ax[i+len(num_cols)].hist(data[num_cols[i]][:100])

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того, вы, мягко говоря, очень своеобразно избавляетесь от пустых строк.

Comment: А как лучше избавиться?)